# How fix dialog deformations when build to a lower OS version?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-developer-api

I am running my android app in my android phone which is OS 8.1 Oreo and it seems no problem with the dialogue, but when i install/build to other phone which is android lollipop the dialogue deform to its original size.

See image below.

[Please click for the image (Error design deform)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bkdG.png)

Source code on dialogue

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogue_dash_date_picker);

        final Spinner spinner = dialog.findViewById(R.id.typeViewSpinner);
        Button btnDismiss = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        String viewType = ViewTypeSingleton.getInstance().getTypeview();
        if (viewType.equals(""))
            spinner.setSelection(0);
        else if (viewType.equals("Day"))
            spinner.setSelection(1);
        else if (viewType.equals("Week"))
            spinner.setSelection(2);
        else if (viewType.equals("Month"))
            spinner.setSelection(3);
        else if (viewType.equals("Year"))
            spinner.setSelection(4);
        else if (viewType.equals("All"))
            spinner.setSelection(5);

        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                String choosen = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                ViewTypeSingleton.getInstance().setTypeview(choosen);
                message.success(""+choosen,context);
                fragmentRedirection(new fragment_main());
            }
        });
        dialog.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Please help me fix this one.

Thanks

Comment: share you style code of dialog

Comment: Okay sir. see above sir. i use the usual code for dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style into your `style.xml`

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

</style>
```

And Create your dialog like this

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Hello sir, it works sir but the next problem is it display on top left side of the screen not on the center :)

Comment: @HardHarryNadela please share your dialogue_dash_date_picker.xml

Comment: wooooohhhh problem solve i just added on my style.xml this line of code

 <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>

Comment: @HardHarryNadela Good luck and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting height and width of dialog using below way:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Mohit Dholakia but still it problem on its display only in center left side, the best answer is the above line i just added on the style.xml 
Anyways thanks for the time solving my problem :)